# How to get multiple file types from FindFirstFile() is it possible?

Tags: c++

If I want to get list of JPEG files I'll pass *.jpg to the function (in the end of the parameter) and FindFileNext() will return .jpg files one by one. What if I want the function to return jpg and mp3 files? is it possible to do it with one function call without making two strings to pass to the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MSDN documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx

You can read:

`lpFileName [in]
The directory or path, and the file name, which can include wildcard characters, for example, an asterisk (*) or a question mark (?).`

So, you can at most use wildcards, which is not enough to match two different extensions.

You might need to perform two searches, first with jpg and second with mp3. If you are concerned about efficiency, ist best to profile each method.

Comment: As I expected apparently this is not possible. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could pass `*.*` mask to the function and do additional checking once you receive next file.

Comment: No I don't want to get all files then check them. This is wasting time and slower running.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to pass several file masks as one parameter.
From the other side, I'm pretty sure FindFirstFile()/FindNextFile() functions do the similar checking internally. So the running won't be slower actually.

Comment: Yes I was thinking about it. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

The answers you've received imply only two possibilities: either search two entirely separate times, once for `*.jpg` and once for `*.mp3`, or else search once for `*.*` (and figure out on your own whether a file matches what you care about or not).

At least in this particular case, there's a little bit of middle ground. You can search for `*.?p?` because the second letter of both extensions you care about is `p`. With this you'll still need to do some sort of comparison on your own to find whether a given file really has one of the two extensions you care about. As such, it won't simplify your code a whole lot.

At the same time, it *can* speed up the search quite a bit. A call to `FindNextFile` has a fair amount of overhead, so if the directory you're looking at has a lot of files that *don't* match the `?p?` extension, avoiding retrieving them all only to ignore them can save quite a bit of time.

Of course, this *is* specific to the case where you have at least one matching letter, so it's not really a completely general technique.